# How to determine if column value is INTEGER inside a trigger?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Here is skeleton of func executed by `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment_indexes()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  IF -- ???

  END IF;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What I need is to determine (using `IF` statement) if `NEW.mycol` is `INTEGER` and not some literal. So `IF` condition should return true for:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycol = 11 WHERE mycol = 10
```

and false for:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1 WHERE mycol = 10
```

Comment: I think you can't. Because your `new.mycol` will always have the value of `11` in both cases. I doubt there's a boolean to distinguish if the `new` value is a pure value or it is somehow calculated.

Comment: Teejay is right: the trigger only ever sees the new value that will be assigned to the column (or has been assigned in an `after` trigger). The information how that value was "generated" is not available in a trigger. The question is: why do you think you need that? What is the **real** problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to make this distinction?

Comment: So the order is: 1. Prepare row for insert (evaluating all literals). 2. execute BEFORE trigger 3. insert row in to table 4. execute AFTER trigger - right? I just wanted to do something with NEW.mycol but I wasnt sure if it is always integer in BEFORE trigger procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to determine if the column value is integer you can use this function, taken from [archives.postgresql.org](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/003601c42ec7$e7806ee0$8401a8c0@home.axiontech.com)

```
CREATE FUNCTION isnumeric(text) RETURNS boolean AS '
SELECT $1 ~ ''^[0-9]+$''
' LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

But your two updates will give you the same result i think.